# Mongoose: Does order of sort, skip and limit matter?

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I realized that I was calling sort after limit, but that didn't cause any issues (calling sort before limit achieves the same result).

```
function mapToSortQuery(sort, search) {
  if (sort == 'recent') {
    return { release_date: -1 }
  } else if (sort == 'popular') {
    return { rating_total: -1 }
  } else if (sort == 'best') {
    return { votes: -1 }
  } else if (sort == 'top') {
    return { rating_avg: -1 }
  } else if (sort == 'trending') {
    return { trend_score: -1 }
  } else if (search) {
    //sort by relevance
    return {
      score: { $meta: 'textScore' },
    }
  } else {
    return { _id: 1 } //sort by id by default
  }
}

router.get('/', async (req, res) => {
  try {
    const { page = 1, limit = 10, sort, search } = req.query //paginated
    const movies = await Movie.find(
      search ? { $text: { $search: search } } : {}
    )
      .limit(limit)
      .skip((page - 1) * limit)
      .sort(mapToSortQuery(sort, search))
      .exec()
    res.send(movies)
  } catch (err) {
    res.status(500).send(err)
  }
})
```

I tested it on MongoDB Compass, and you can only sort on the items that are present after limit, instead of all the items which is the desired behavior.
[image]

So now I am confused by why my original code worked as intended.

Also, I am confused by the distinction between queries (find) and aggregation (match); should I be using match <s>instead of mixing find with other aggregation methods</s>(Edit: actually limit and skip are also query methods)?

Comment: _"you can only sort on the items after limit"_  Just tested it on MongoDB Atlas with Compass - you can `"$sort"` before `"$limit"`.  This is the typical order of the stages.  There could be a problem if the sort exceeds the size limit imposed by the server.